# How to get "id" without user and pass

Tags: php

how to keep the id(to use it later) when the user enter the username and password in a login page in PHP.
like if want to login to reserve for example , to save the reserve i need the id of the person so how should i get it without using username and password

Comment: do you mean "cookie"?

Comment: to use later? or to use the next time they come back to the site?

Comment: yeah and if there another way it will be good

Comment: Trying to read this first: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple,

First, When user success-login to system, make some sessions.

```
    session_start();
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT `ID`,`Username`,`Name` FROM `users` WHERE `Username` = '$username' AND `Password` = '$password' LIMIT 1;");
    if(mysql_num_rows($sql) == 1) { // Check if the user really exists
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
    $_SESSION['ID'] = $row['ID']; // Make new session.
    $_SESSION['Username'] = $row['Username'];
    echo "Welcome, ".$_SESSION['Username']."!";
    }
```

The session will be destroy after the client close the browser.

You can try do it with cookie.. But it will be less secure..

Work? (:

Comment: very helpful thank you

Answer (score 0):

To keep the id while they are logged in you can place this at the top of your login page

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}
```

Then on successful login create a session variable

```
$_SESSION['id'] = $row['ID'];
```

Hope this helps.